# Binary search in C++

Tags: c++

Basically I need to find out how to make the values output on screen for the success part of my binary search. I tried to change the initial value of `last` but it either crashes or remains the same.  I stepped through the code and everything seems to be working right.

**Program Sample from compiler**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void binarySearch();

int main()
{
    //Called the function in main
    binarySearch();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};

//void function for binary Search
void binarySearch()
{
      //creating array
      int array[100];
       array[0] = 1;
       int i,target;
      // using Boolean to create pattern for generated numbers in the array
      bool check = false;

      //loop to implement pattern
      for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
      {
        if (check == true)
        {
           array[x] = array[x - 1] + 1;
           check = false;
        }
        else
        {   
           array[x] = array[x - 1] + 2; 
           check = true;

        }
       }

     **Code found online and modified to fit**  

  int first,mid,last,completed,successful,tests;
  completed = 0;
  successful = 0;
  tests = 0;
  double percentage;
  percentage = 1;

  for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
  {
    // Initialize first and last variables.
    first = 0;
    last = 2;
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );      
    int target = (rand() % 150) + 1;

    while(first <= last)
    {
       mid = (first + last)/2;

       if(target > array[mid])
       {
          first = mid + 1;
          tests++;          
       }
       else if(target < array[mid])
       {
          last = mid + 1;
          tests++;
       }
       else
       {
          first = last - 1;
       }
       if(target == array[mid])
       {
          successful++;
       }
    }
    completed++;
  } 

**Area which the error occur No value for successful**
//Output on screen
cout << endl;
cout << "There were "<< completed <<" searches completed."<< endl; 
cout << "There were "<< successful <<" successful searches." << endl; 
cout << percentage <<"%"<<" of the searches were successful." << endl; 
cout << "There was an average of " << completed << " tests per search." << endl;
cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: You might have better results if your initial value of `last` is somewhere around the total number of elements to search, instead of 2.

Comment: Well I tried to change the initial value of **last** but it either crashes or remains the same.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Basically I need to find out how to make values output on screen for the success part of my binary search.

Comment: @CraigCampbell: did you step through the code line by line in a debugger and follow along?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but `srand` should not appear inside a for loop. It's typically meant to be called exactly once and then never again.

Comment: Is there some particularly good reason to write your own binary search instead of using `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I did yes I did and everything seems about right

Comment: Craig, I edited your question in response to your two recent comments, but it will still not prevent this question from receiving any more down-votes, sorry.

Comment: @Kevin: I need the target number to be randomly generated each time it loops for the binary search to do it's job.

Comment: @CraigCampbell `srand` seeds the random number generator, so there's no need to keep re-seeding it every loop. With the way the code is, if your `for` loop is called faster than the resolution of the `time` function, `rand` will produce the same result as the earlier iteration.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Used it to learn how it really works based on using unique variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd start by breaking the code up into somewhat smaller pieces, each of which I could at least hope to understand; I'm not smart enough to be sure I understand as big of "chunks" as your `binarySearch`.

It looks like this much:

```
  int array[100];
   array[0] = 1;
   int i,target;
  // using Boolean to create pattern for generated numbers in the array
  bool check = false;

  //loop to implement pattern
  for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
  {
    if (check == true)
    {
       array[x] = array[x - 1] + 1;
       check = false;
    }
    else
    {   
       array[x] = array[x - 1] + 2; 
       check = true;

    }
   }
```

Is supposed to initialize an array, so I'd put it in a separate function, and then simplify it a bit. First into a function:

```
int init(int array[100]) {
   array[0] = 1;
   int i,target;
  // using Boolean to create pattern for generated numbers in the array
  bool check = false;

  //loop to implement pattern
  for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
  {
    if (check == true)
    {
       array[x] = array[x - 1] + 1;
       check = false;
    }
    else
    {   
       array[x] = array[x - 1] + 2; 
       check = true;

    }
   }
}
```

then simplified:

```
int init(int *array) { 
    array[0] = 1;

    for (int i=1; i<100; i++)
        array[i] = array[i-1] + 1 + (i&1);
}
```

Then I'd do roughly the same with the binary search part of `binarySearch`:

```
while(first <= last)
{
   mid = (first + last)/2;

   if(target > array[mid])
   {
      first = mid + 1;
      tests++;          
   }
   else if(target < array[mid])
   {
      last = mid + 1;
      tests++;
   }
   else
   {
      first = last - 1;
   }
   if(target == array[mid])
   {
      successful++;
   }
```

and simplified:

```
int *binary_search(int const *left, int const *right, int *tests, int val) { 
    int const *mid = left + (right - left)/2;

    while (left < right) {
        ++*tests;
        if (val < *mid)
            right = mid;
        else
            left = mid + 1;
    }
    return left;
}
```

Finally, you'll need the code to generate a random number, search for it, track the statistics on number of searches and how many were successful, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.

First, as I commented, you are not initializing `last` correctly.

Second, in the `else if(target < array[mid])` case, you are not modifying `last` correctly. You are setting `last = mid + 1;` but you need to instead set `last = mid - 1;`

Next, you are not exiting your loop correctly. You only exit the while loop if first > last, but you should instead exit it once `target == array[mid]`; perhaps a strategic `break;` statement would help.

When I make these three changes, the application runs till completion every time, however I either receive 0 or 100 successful searches -- nothing in between.

This should be enough to get you much further along though.