# Having problems running a simple binary search on c++

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am new to programming and now I am going over binary searches on c++. I ran a binary search when I first learned it and it worked fine but ever since I've been trying to replicate it by myself it keeps displaying "Sorry we did not find your number" and when I display the return value, it always returns -1 (it was never changed in the loop). I'll leave the code below:

```
int main(){

int 
numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
searchValue = 8,
returnValue = -1,
low = 0,
high = ARR_SIZE,
mid = (low + high) / 2;

while(low < high)
{
    if(numbers[mid] == searchValue)
    {
        returnValue = mid;
        break;
    }
    else if(numbers[mid] < searchValue)
    {
        low = mid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        high = mid - 1;
    }
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
}

if(returnValue == -1)
{
    cout << "Sorry we did not find the number" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "We found your number! It is located at index " << returnValue << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary search in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537100/binary-search-in-c)

Comment: What is `ARR_SIZE`?

Comment: Try `while (low <= high)`. For your test case eventually both are 7 and instead of finding the number you skip that last check.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite simple:

Replace the `while (low < high)` to `while (low <= high)`. It works for me. Cheers!

I would like to credit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798622/binary-search-on-c-the-while-loop) thread of Stack Overflow. It helped me to understand where the problem in your code was.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ARRAY_SIZE if the length of an array.

You need to change your while loop condition to `while ((low <= high))`
Because of `low < high` it is not going in the loop when low==high.

You can add `mid<10` to avoid array bound out of scope in while with &&.
This will save your last iteration.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I applied the <= and it worked wonders thank you very much, and I will apply your tip :)